# why there is no site for games question answers

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

In Stack Exchange we can see sites for Role Playing Games, Chess, and even LEGO, but there is no site for say: FPS games, or Puzzle Games, or as one general site of Games Q/A..

Is that against some policy of the site ? or is it just seen as an unnecessary task ? I see people going hardly to forums, even commenting on YouTube videos to get answers when they are stuck in games, or game stories.

Comment: All games ever might be a little broad, but I can't see why you couldn't propose this on area51

Comment: Or do you just mean computer games, if so see Johns answer

Comment: @RichardTingle, hopefully for at least FPS he means a computer simulation ;-)

Comment: @Peter ha Indeed, it was puzzle games that threw me into all games (although of course you do get puzzle computer games)

Comment: Lego is not a game, it stands out in your list of examples. I'm not really sure why there would be a FPS Games site, as I think for all of them you just shoot things. And for all those stories getting stuck there is the Arqade as mentioned by John Palmer.

Comment: And Arquade (Gaming.SE) does not deal with speculation.

Comment: @Amber, you are underestimating FPS games, the most questions asked in the gaming world are about strategy games and FPS games. Games are getting larger every day, sometimes you get stuck, Half Life game series needs a lot of questions for example.

Comment: We have a pretty solid history on Arqade showing that FPS consistently get fewer questions than RPGs and sandbox games (which are the top categories by number of questions per game). There are just far more potential questions about Skyrim than about Call of Duty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the footer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Even though there is actually already a site for gaming, [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the place to drop suggestions for new sites and see if there are enough like-minded folks who think that your suggestion is good enough to warrant a new site.

Comment: @TechSupport - I think you are reading too much into a perfectly innocent phrase.

Comment: @TechSupport I meant if there are enough people that want to create the site that is suggested. Don't see how that is rude in any way, shape or form. What did you assume I meant by it?

Comment: @TechSupport See the definition of like-minded [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/like-minded); "agreeing in opinions, goals, etc"